# Carácter de término en Java

Tags: java, string, stdout

Me surgió una duda acerca de porqué el carácter de término es ignorado al momento de mandar a **STDOUT** una secuencia de caracteres.

Por ejemplo, en C cuando haces la impresión

```
printf("%s", "hello\0world");
```

El output llega hasta `\0`, pues es el carácter que indica que ahí termina la secuencia de caracteres, es decir sólo imprime `hello`

Sin embargo, al reproducir este mismo comportamiento en Java sólo se ignora este carácter

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    char[] hello = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
    System.out.println(hello);
    System.out.println("hello\0world");
}
```

y el output es `helloworld`, ¿Por qué sucede esto?, ¿Es cuestión del compilador?.

Si no interviene el compilador, ¿Entonces cómo distingue cuál es el verdadero carácter de término?

Comment: Si bien java hereda parte de su sintaxis del lenguaje C, no hay que asumir que Java es 
 C, en dado caso java no implementa la funcionalidad de `Null-terminated string` y simplemente omite el carácter.

Comment: Ya java y otros lenguajes posteriores a c++, liberan al programador de especificar el fin de la cadena, asi que no te preocupes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El \0, si bien el compilador lo cuenta como un caracter de la secuencia, no se utiliza en java para terminar la secuencia de caracteres. Java no utiliza "null-terminated" para los Strings, simplemente utiliza un array de char para representar el String y provee un metodo llamado "length" para saber el numero de caracteres en dicho String (el cual tambien toma en cuenta el \0).